# How to measure mobile browser rendering time using real device

Tags: android, ios, mobile, performance-testing, response-time

I am doing a performance testing on a web application.

I want to record the Load Time or Response Time of the browser.

In desktop browser, I will use developer tools > Network to get the data I want.

**But how I able to get the REAL DEVICE's browser response time?**

**Remark : I have eliminated using browser emulator since it doesn't represent the actual real device's spec.

Answer (score 1):

you should use android device monitor in android studio

tools> android> android device monitor

Comment: how about iOS device? I don't have any MAC pc

Comment: i dont know about ios. but you dont have a pc or mac? so you want to test on your device itself?

Comment: I have a window PC.
Ya. I want to test on the real device to get the more accurate result. 
Is there anway?

Comment: you can use a real device with the android device monitor just open the device monitor plug your device in and open your app